# Overriding Application Name Localization Behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, localization, android-manifest

My app works on two languages , English and Arabic . here i want to have Arabic instance of the application when the device language is English . i've done this in code and it works , but the problem is when the language is English , the application name turn to English name and not it's Arabic name , can i override this behavior somehow?

Comment: My advice would be not to fight the system. I had similar issues, and I came down to let everything work as is. If the device's language is English, use English. If it's Arabic, use Arabic.